# how can in perfectly inscribe a triangle inside a square in python turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am learning python turtle and I just wanted to create a cool figure but came across this problem. I want to inscribe a triangle inside the center Square perfectly.
Here's my code,

```
import turtle

dadu=turtle.Turtle()

dadu.forward(100)
dadu.right(90)
dadu.forward(100)
dadu.right(90)
dadu.forward(100)
dadu.right(90)
dadu.forward(100)

dadu.forward(100)

dadu.forward(100)
dadu.right(90)
dadu.forward(100)
dadu.right(90)
dadu.forward(100)
dadu.right(90)
dadu.forward(100)

dadu.forward(100)

#square 3
dadu.forward(100)
dadu.right(90)
dadu.forward(100)
dadu.right(90)
dadu.forward(100)
dadu.right(90)
dadu.forward(100)

dadu.forward(100)

dadu.forward(100)
dadu.right(90)
dadu.forward(100)
dadu.right(90)
dadu.forward(100)
dadu.right(90)
dadu.forward(100)

dadu.forward(100)

dadu.left(120)
dadu.forward(115)
dadu.left(120)
dadu.forward(115)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Here is the result,[python turtle result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfz4g.png)

Comment: Change the angle

Comment: Do you want an equilateral triangle? Do you want the base of the triangle and square to match? Do you want all 3 corners to touch the square? You can't have all 3.

Comment: I feel like you should be modifying the value inside the `dadu.left(120)` at the end of the script to 110 or so, and see what that does?

Comment: It's possible to inscribe an equilateral triangle in a square : https://socratic.org/questions/given-the-equilateral-triangle-inscribed-in-a-square-of-side-s-find-the-ratio-of As mentioned by @AlexHall: It cannot have a common side with the square, though.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the page that @EricDuminil cites in his comment, and everything else on this topic (most of which are concerned with area), the largest *equilateral* triangle inscribed in a square looks like this:

```
import turtle
from math import sqrt, radians, cos

SQUARE_RADIUS = 100  # adjust as desired

ANGLE = radians(15)
TRIANGLE_RADIUS = sqrt((SQUARE_RADIUS / cos(ANGLE)) ** 2 * 2) * sqrt(3) / 3

turtle.circle(SQUARE_RADIUS, steps=4)
turtle.circle(TRIANGLE_RADIUS, steps=3)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

[image]

As far as finishing your drawing cleanly with an *isosceles* triangle, I'd go with:

```
import turtle

def square():
    for _ in range(3):
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.right(90)

    turtle.forward(200)

for _ in range(4):
    square()

turtle.goto(turtle.xcor() - 50, turtle.ycor() + 100)
turtle.goto(turtle.xcor() - 50, turtle.ycor() - 100)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: Well executed, thanks for implementing and testing the idea.